# Reverse-then-add sequence: Big-O runtime of my solution?

Tags: java, math, big-o, time-complexity, recurrence

First of all, this is not homework: I submitted some Java code on CodeEval.

The challenge boils down to the following question:

> Start with a number n. If it's a palindrome, stop. Otherwise, reverse the digits of n, add them to n, and repeat this process. Report how many steps are necessary before the number converges to a palindrome.

It wasn't difficult at all. Moreover, once I submitted the code and received 100% on the challenge I began looking over my code again - I wanted to determine the time complexity of my recursive call method and my method being called within the recursive method.

Wherein, I came up with:

```
//adds the i'th integer in String[] data to its reversed integer:
private final int add(int x)
{
    //if x is 0, then don't do anymore computation
    if(x==0)
    {
        count++;   
        return x;
    }
    //if x equals its reversal, the palindrome has been found
    if(x==rev(x))
    {
      return x;
    }

    //keep adding and reversing
    else
    {
        //if MAX has been reached, STOP
         if (count==MAX)
         return 0;

         //increment the count
         count++;
        _intTmp=rev(x); //get the reversal 

        return add(x + _intTmp); //recursive call: keep adding
    }//else:end
} //Main::add() end
```

So ... I calculated T(N): 1 + log(1/n)

```
//reverse the integer: worst case is O(N)
private final int rev(int orig) 
{
    int reversed=0;
    while(orig>0)
    {
        //adds the last digit from orig to reversed
        reversed=reversed*10+orig%10; 
        orig=orig/10; //gets rid of the last digit    
    }
    return reversed; //return the reversed integer  
}//Main::final end
```

I calculated: O(N)

The overall time complexity, of this code snippet, is: O(1+log(1/n)+n) ~ O(N)

Am I right, or did I mess up somewhere?

Thank you for your time and advice ...

Comment: Why do you need separate add function? After reversing the number you can directly add those?

Comment: why do you invoke rev twice ?  Why not just store rev(x) once at the top and use it in both the base case and the recursive step?  Also your base case condition can be collapsed into a single if

Comment: Thank you for your input. This was my first proof-of-concept program for the challenge. Of course, after a couple of days, I usually come back, optimize and revise the code. 

Both of you made awesome observations, however, how about the computed time complexity?

Comment: Even if I did integrate everything in rev(), into add(), it would not change the time complexity much. However, calling rev() once instead of twice would eliminate repetitive processing, and optimize the code.  At the end of the day, it boils down to a few things: personal style; code readability; design pattern(s) and; portability.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you get the log (1 / n) term from. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

I think that no one knows what the big-O runtime of this function will be or if it even has one at all. The challenge hints that it's unknown whether certain numbers eventually form palindromes this way. In fact, it's an open problem in mathematics; such a number is called a [Lychrel number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number) and no one knows whether they exist or not!

If a number of this form exists, your algorithm would enter an infinite loop when run on it, so there would be no upper-bound to the runtime on that input. On the other hand, if no numbers of this form exist, the runtime bound would depend on the total number of times that you had to add the reverse of the number to itself to form a palindrome.

However, for now, let's suppose that there is a bound to the number of iterations necessary. Let's suppose that for any number n, there's a number f(n) that tells you how many times you have to use the reverse-the-digits-and-add trick. Notice that every time you reverse the digits and add, the number goes up by at most a factor of 9. Adding d-digit numbers takes time O(d), and reversing a d-digit number also takes time O(d). Also, note that a number n has O(log n) digits in it. Therefore, the runtime would be

> log n + 9 log n + 9<sup>2</sup> log n + ... + 9<sup>f(n)</sup> log n
>
> = O(9<sup>f(n)</sup> log n)

So if there is indeed an upper bound f(n) on the number of steps necessary, the runtime would be O(9<sup>f(n)</sup> log n).

I'm not sure how you got O(1 + 1 / log n) as your runtime for the main step. If you provide more detail about how you arrived at that, I can try to help look over your logic in some more detail.

Hope this helps!